# Unable to send email inside async route with Express and NodeMailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

### Issue

I am having trouble attempting to send an email with NodeMailer after saving some data to a file via the fs module.

### Rundown

I have an api route that accepts some very basic JSON data:

```
{
   "name": "Some Name",
   "email": "example@gmail.com",
   "linkedIn": "https://linkedin.com/38473289472",
   "comments": ""
}
```

When my route receives that data, it attempts to save that data to a JSON file. It does this by reading the current JSON file to see if the person already exists, and if not, it writes to the file.

This works great, but my problem is when I try to send an email after this process occurs. Here is the code in its entirety:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@email.com',
    pass: 'somecoolpassword',
  },
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'myemail@email.com',
  to: 'myemail@email.com',
  subject: 'subject',
  html: `test`,
};

// This is the route
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await addApplicant(req.body);
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions); // Does not send
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
};

const addApplicant = async applicant => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./applicants/applicants.json', 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
      if (err)
        reject('There was an error accessing the applicants master file.');

      const allApplicants = JSON.parse(data);

      if (allApplicants.hasOwnProperty(applicant.email)) {
        reject('User already exists.');
      }

      const updatedApplicants = JSON.stringify({
        ...allApplicants,
        [applicant.email]: { ...applicant },
      });

      await writeToJsonFile(updatedApplicants);
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

const writeToJsonFile = async updatedApplicants => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile('./applicants/applicants.json', updatedApplicants, err => {
      if (err) reject('There was an error saving the applicants information');
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

If I change the register route to send the email BEFORE I start using the filesystem, it sends the email, and performs the proper file operations.

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions); // works
    await addApplicant(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? It honestly has to be something so trivial, but I just cannot see it right now.

Comment: I don't think it'll solve you issue but it seems the `sendMail` is not an async method. So you can't await it, you need a callback.

Comment: Do you really  need to use await for sendMail?

Comment: Yes. It does not work anywhere inside of the async register function without the await keyword in front of it.

Comment: Actually what I said is incorrect. It doesnt matter at all if I use the await keyword with  it. The call to addApplicant just needs to be commented out.

Comment: Pretty sure it might have to something to do with how I am "promisifying" the fs read and write file methods. If I instead create a generic method that returns a promise, and run that before running transporter.sendMail(mailOptions) it still sends the email.